# how to get all inner documents inside collection to object in kotlin (Firebase Firestore)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Pic 1]

What I know

```
Collection
Caterer     -------
        Document 1
        Document 2
                 .
                 . 
                 .
```

I did

```
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    db.collection("User_Events")
        .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
            override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {

                if(error!= null) {
                    return
                }

                for (dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){

                    if(dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                        eventarraylist.add(dc.document.toObject(EventsData::class.java))
                    }
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
        })
```

[image: pic 2]

[image: pic 3]

now how to get all inner documents if it is like

Collection (User_Events) --- Documents --- Collection --- Documents (Wanna get all inner Documents)

How can I achieve it in Kotlin?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also indicate what are the exact documents that you need to read.

Comment: If you want to list events of all users then you could have used [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#kotlin+ktx_15) queries but you won't be able to use them as your sub-collection IDs is different i.e. the emails. I would recommend creating DB like `users -> {uid} -> events -> {eventId}` so you can use `collectionGroup("event")`. Alternatively, you can create a root level collection "events" and store user's UID as a field in them.